# What data will be stored in the idsrv cookie of the IdentityServer4?

Tags: vue.js, cookies, identityserver4, idsrv

I would like to use the IdentityServer for the "authentication part" of my single page application. I noticed that some cookies are generated. So I read the documentation of the IdentityServer to get more informationen about the idsrv cookie. The only information I could find was "In addition to the authentication cookie, IdentityServer will issue an additional cookie which defaults to the name “idsrv.session”. This cookie is derived from the main authentication cookie, and it used for the check session endpoint for browser-based JavaScript clients at signout time. It is kept in sync with the authentication cookie, and is removed when the user signs out."
Does anybody know what data will be stored in the idsrv cookie?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The idsrv.session cookie is very short, like this one:

```
Set-Cookie: idsrv.session=FEB09F3BA38A51C77FF680ACB11BBAFF; path=/; secure; samesite=none
```

and you can find where it is set [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4/src/Services/Default/DefaultUserSession.cs) in the **IssueSessionIdCookie** method and the value is just a random session ID.

You can find how that one is generated in the **CreateSessionIdAsync** using

```
CryptoRandom.CreateUniqueId(16, CryptoRandom.OutputFormat.Hex));
```

the **idsrv** cookie cookie is set by the **cookie authenticatio**n scheme and that cookie typically contains the user details of the logged in user. Including some of the claims about that user. The cookie is protected using the Data Protection API.

so when you do a full authentication cycle with openid connect, you establish one login session with IdentityServer and one with your clients.

Hope that answers your question.

ps, if you want to peek inside the cookies, then I have a blog post about that here: https://nestenius.se/2023/11/22/exploring-what-is-inside-the-asp-net-core-cookies/

Comment: Thanks. Is the data of the identity token the same as in the idsrv cookie?

Comment: I am sorry. I don't understand it. In my understanding the identity token contains information about who you are and the access token contains information about if the user is allowed to access to an protected resource. So why I need the idsrv cookie?

Comment: the idserv cookie is needed so that for example if the user goes from one application to an another application that both uses the same IdentityServer, then the user does not need to login again, perhaps only give consent to new scopes needed. Basically, this is how we get a single-signin experience. Otherwise it would be much harder to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks. I think I got it. It is possible to prevent generating this cookie? I think I don't need this cookie. But if the cookie will be still generated the user has to accept the use of cookies via a pop-up or something similar.

Comment: I don't know how much you can customize this cookie or "how" required this cookie is for the operation of IdentityServer. but in general , not accepting cookies, then not much of the web would work as logging in requires cookies.

Comment: if my answer is an good answer to your question, then you can mark it as accepted here in stack oveflow.